# Where can I find (and change) the markup used by "render 'flashes'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, renderpartial

This is my first project using Ruby on Rails and I'm working on the front-end code; the back-end developer is new to rails too. One template includes the code `render 'flashes'`, which is triggered when there is an error on a form submission; but the markup it generates is messed up, and I'd like to fix it. Here's an example. The `<!-- comments -->` are mine:

```
<div id="flash">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div title="Error" class="error"></div>  <!-- Empty div -->
        <p>Please enter a valid email</p>      <!-- p element sibling of div.error -->
      </div>                                   <!-- Closes div.wrapper -->
    </div>                                     <!-- Closes div#flash -->
</div>                                         <!-- Extra /div closes parent div -->
```

I would prefer to use one `div` for the message, but the biggest problem is the extra closing `div` tag at the end, which closes a parent division, messing up the layout.

I see that the error message is defined in the controller as `flash[:error] = "Please enter a valid email"`, but I don't know where rails is getting this bogus markup. Is there a `_flashes` partial I can edit to fix this problem? I've pored over the project's filesystem, and it's not clear to me where this markup lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `_flashes.html.erb` file in the Rails source. If you're seeing

```
render 'flashes'
```

in your application, you or some generator you ran put it there. Look through the files in `app/views/` for one called `_flashes.html.erb` that contains the markup you provided in your Question. Once you find that file you should be able to modify it however you need to fix your broken HTML issue.

If you can't find it there, look at your list of gems in your `Gemfile`, specifically for one that relates to theming/templating. It's possilbe you've included a gem that contains this template file *(though much less likely than the file existing in `app/views/`)*.

Comment: Thanks, Deefour. I've verified that there is no file in app/views with "flashes" in the name-- I ran `find .|grep flash` in my project directory and nothing came up. The only gems I installed related to templating are haml and sass, but the backend developer might have installed some others. I'll investigate, but I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: I think I found the culprit. This command revealed three partials that are part of html5-rails: `GEMDIR=$(gem env gemdir); find $GEMDIR | grep flashes;` Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like they fixed it in gem's repository, but it's not available via `bundle update` yet.

Comment: Run "rails generate html5:partial _flashes" in your console and it will generate the flashes file for you.